# How to enable ONTOLOGICAL search in Marklogic?

Tags: marklogic, ontology, marklogic-9

How to enable the ontological search in Marklogic?

Eg: User types "Probable". Then result set should have both "Probable" and "likely".

Thanks!

Comment: For future questions, you will be more likely to get help if you also include the [marklogic] tag.